# Got ExceptionInInitializerError when mocking constructor of a class with Powermock. How to fix it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, powermock

Here is my case. I have a AbstractController class. It has a sub class Controller. In one of AbstractController's methods a new ApplicationLock is instantiated. I'd like to mock ApplicationLock when writing ut for Controller.  I wrote a test case like below.

```
@test
public void testMethod(){
    ApplicationLock mockLock=PowerMockito.mock(ApplicationLock.class);
    PowerMockito.when(mockLock.tryObtain()).thenReturn(true);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ApplicationLock.class).withArguments(argThat(new IsFile()),anyString()).thenReturn(mockLock);
}
```

I've added necessary annotations to the test class.

> @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
>
> @PrepareForTest({AbstractController.class})

But I got the following error when running this test case. That is a static initializer in AbstractController.

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.acompany.controller.common.AbstractController.(AbstractController.java:65)**

```
private static final String DEFAULT_FOLDER = AbstractController.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
            .getLocation().getPath();
```

Full stack trace is as below.

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)   at
>   javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassObject(Desc.java:44)   at
>   javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:153)    at
>   javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:123)     at
>   javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:79)  at
>   com.acompany.controller.portfolio.ControllerTest.testIncrementalFail(ControllerTest.java:195)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)  at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:307)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.acompany.controller.common.AbstractController.(AbstractController.java:65)
>     ... 35 more

Answer (score 3):

You could use then:

```
 @SuppressStaticInitializationFor({AbstractController.class})
```

And then, in your test case, set manually all static fields that need to be initialized, including the DEFAULT_FOLDER:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(Controller.class, "DEFAULT_FOLDER", "abcd");
Whitebox.setInternalState(Controller.class, "OTHER_FIELD", new Object());
```

The method `Class<?>.getProtectionDomain()` depends too much on class loader used, so you probably won't get it to work in JUnit/PowerMock, which use their own.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it. But I cannot suppress all static initializers in AbstractController. I will get null pointer if I do so.