# Using Gradle test fixtures with PowerMock

Tags: java, gradle, powermock

I am using PowerMock to verify a static call to JavaCC in a Gradle task.

In my @Before annotated method (I'm using JUnit4 and Mockito, BTW), I have this:

```
Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build();
```

When I run any test case in this class annotated with

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

I get the following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.gradle.testfixtures.internal.ProjectBuilderImpl
at org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder.<init>(ProjectBuilder.java:46)
at org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder.builder(ProjectBuilder.java:54)
at ca.coglinc.gradle.plugins.javacc.CompileJavaccTaskTest.setUp(CompileJavaccTaskTest.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:132)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:95)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I think I am missing the Gradle runtime configuration on my test classpath, but can not find how to fix it. Removing the PowerMockRunner, my tests run correctly, but then I can't have a test that depends on PowerMock (I know stuff should be testable without requiring PowerMock, but I'm not writing JavaCC and still want to verify that it's called with some parameters). Any ideas?

Comment: If it's for tests only You should probably add `testCompile gradleApi()` in the `dependencies` block.

Comment: I already have `compile gradleApi()` which to my understanding will also include it under the testCompile and testRuntime configurations. Proof that this works is that my tests compile just fine. However, I tried it just in case and it still fails with the same error.

Comment: There's one more thing I don't understand: when I run `gradle dependencies`the gradleApi dependencies do not show up at all under any configuration.

Comment: Yes `compile` is also added to `test*`. No idea why `gradleApi()` isn't shown when `gradle dependencies` is run. It rather should be. Do You have a SSCCE somewhere on the web?

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/johnmartel/javaccPlugin and run `./gradlew clean :javacc-gradle-plugin:test` you'll get the error. I added javassist and objenesis to my test classpath and I get a slightly more precise stack trace in the initialization of ProjectBuilderImpl, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592018/got-exceptionininitializererror-when-mocking-constructor-of-a-class-with-powermo?rq=1) was spot on! I wasn't able to make the PowerMockRunner work with the PojectBuilderImpl, but at least now I know why. I tried suppressing the static initializers, but then all sorts of things are broken. I finally abandoned the idea of unit testing this little part of my code and will rely on my acceptance tests instead.

Please note that Opal's answer works, but I don't want to add useTestNG() to my build file, since I am not actually using it. This seems too counterintuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify **<ROOT>/plugin/build.gradle**, change:

```
test {
    maxParallelForks = 10
    forkEvery = 50
}
```

to:

```
test {
    useTestNG()
    maxParallelForks = 10
    forkEvery = 50
}
```

It seems that `TestNG` should be used to run the tests.

Comment: I don't want to use TestNG at all, I'm using the JUnit 4.4+ PowerMockRunner. My question is for this configuration in particular

Comment: Ok, my tests are still JUnit tests, but adding useTestNG() DOES fix the problem, do you have an explanation for that to work?

Comment: It know it does solve the problem, that's why I submitted the answer :) What this method does is switching framework used from `JUnit` to `TestNG`. Why it helps? It seems that `PowerMockRunner` is incompatible with `JUnit` - here's a very old issue: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=375 that still has *Accepted* status.